# BindingAdapter with coroutine scope

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm not sure if I'm using `CoroutineScope` properly inside my Binding Adapter function:

```
@BindingAdapter("srcByFileName")
fun setImageViewResource(imageView: ImageView, fileName: String?) {
    if(fileName == null) return

    CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val bitmap = ImageStorageManager.getImageFromInternalStorage(imageView.context, fileName)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }

}
```

I need to move the fetching of `Bitmap` to a different thread hence the need of coroutine. I'm just wondering if this is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: You forgot to cancel the job, it may cause leaks. Save a reference to the job and cancel it when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Data Binding**, then your logic would probably be in your `ViewModel`, so it's better to pass `viewModelScope` to the `BindingAdapter` function.

Just add a third parameter of type `CoroutineScope` which you can pass from xml layout through the predefined `viewModel` object.

And in `ViewModel`, you can just define your scope like this:

```
val scope: CoroutineScope
    get() = viewModelScope
```

And in xml:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="ViewModelType" />
</data>

...

<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:srcByFileName=@{viewModel.src}
   app:coroutineScope="@{viewModel.scope}" />
```